# Debian 8, ping 127.0.0.1 not working

Tags: debian, networking, iptables, iptables-persistent

On my Debian 8 `uname -a' gives:

```
Linux uname 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u1 (2016-09-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Tried

`route -n` gives:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.2        0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
```

Other networing functions are fine.

How can I get `ping 127.0.0.1` to work?  I suspect it is the following `!lo` rule in `iptables` but I do no know how to fix it and make the changes persistent.

```
3591 2197K ACCEPT     all  --  !lo    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

This line appears as:  `-A INPUT ! -i lo -j ACCEPT`
in `/etc/iptables.up.rules`

Do I delete the `!`?

Comment: Please post the results for ifconfig (without -a).

Comment: ifconfig lists `lo` and `eth0` as expected.  Do you want me to include it as it is now as I do not believe it contains any value?

Comment: No its fine. But maybe you need to include this: iptables -t filter -L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Debian 8 `iptables` denied loopback access on `localhost` in my installation.

Many programs requires this to function correctly, such as debuggers, so I do not understand how it was disabled in my setup.

The fix is as follows:

Root edit `/etc/iptables.up.rules` and change `-A INPUT ! -i lo -j ACCEPT` to `-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT` by deleting the bang!

Answer (score 1):

No, Jessie didn't block by default.

```
ping -c 4 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 2999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.044/0.051/0.056/0.004 ms
```

Show `iptables -L` and  `cat /etc/hosts` `cat /etc/hostname`

Comment: The offending line in `iptables -L` includes the `!lo` listed above.  I am not sure how it was changed if your version is the same?

Comment: uname -a
3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u1 (2016-09-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux I never changed iptables rules iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: I have no idea where the bang Lo rule on my system came from.  Thanks for pointing this out.